# Die Bedeutung von "kühl reagieren"

Tags: meaning

Aus dem [Spiegel-Online](http://m.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/a-1015076.html#spRedirectedFrom=www&referrrer=https://www.google.com/):

> Der neue linke Ministerpräsident Tsipras lässt sich in Athen feiern. Berlin `reagiert kühl`. Kanzlerin Angela Merkel und ihr Finanzminister wollen sich von der neuen griechischen Regierung nicht treiben lassen.

Ich möchte wissen, was bedeutet `kühl reagieren`.  Ist das dasselbe wie `durch nichts aus der Ruhe zu bringen sein` ?

Comment: Maybe you are mistaking it for "einen kühlen Kopf bewahren"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nein, es ist eine verhaltene, eher negative Reaktion. Nicht gerade begeistert, sozusagen.

Comment: Es bedeutet to react with caution?

Comment: @DerPolyglott33... no, it's about a lack of enthusiasm or any other kind of emotion for that matter. Greece does something many find epic or crazy and Berlin is just like "Acknowledged! Don't know about that."

Comment: Axo, danke für die Erklärung!

Answer (score 0):

It means they did not exactly congratulate him for being elected.